# How to speed up or replace the nested loops

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

Can I ask is there any other way to speed up or replace the nested loops?

I am trying to capture the data from excel file there are 66 rows of data with each "A, B, C, D" lines

```
import xlwings as xw
import glob as glob   
import itertools   
letters = ['A','B','C','D'] 
    for i in range(66):
            for j in range(len(letters)):
                sht1 = wb.sheets['Pallet Configurations']
                val = (sht1.range(letters[j] + str(i+2)).options(numbers=str).value)
                valueList[j].append(val)
```

I try to use itertools.product but it's not working.

```
    for i, j in itertools.product(66,len(letters)):
        sht1 = wb.sheets['Pallet Configurations']
        val = (sht1.range(letters[j] + str(i+2)).options(numbers=str).value)
        valueList[j].append(val)
```

Comment: Hi @kkkk, welcome to the site. Giving an answer that will help you fix your use of `itertools.product` would be easy, but I'm not sure it will be a satisfactory answer to the whole question, since it's unlikely to speed up your code very much. The slow stuff is probably not the loop itself, but what you're doing inside of it. That looks like some sort of spreadsheet stuff, but as you haven't tagged the library you're using, nor said anything about it in the question body, we can't help you speed it up. Can you [edit] your question to add some tags and descriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly which library you are using to manipulate what looks like workbook sheets, however you shouldn't need to set `sht1` every time in your inner for loop. Your code could be written as:

```
sht1 = wb.sheets['Pallet Configurations']
letters = ['A','B','C','D'] 
for i in range(66):
        for j in range(len(letters)):
            val = (sht1.range(letters[j] + str(i+2)).options(numbers=str).value)
            valueList[j].append(val)
```

This should save you needing to call `.sheets` on `wb` each time. Additionally, it looks like whichever library you are using can read in a range of of cells at a time. It would probably be less expensive to read the whole row once, before you enter your inner loop. You could then take advantage of Python's [`List.extend()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm) method to add the entire list of cells to `valueList`.

Sample code might look like:

```
sht1 = wb.sheets['Pallet Configurations']
letters = ['A','B','C','D'] 
for i in range(66):
    for j in range(len(letters)):
        letter = str(letters[j])
        vals = (sht1.range("{0}{1}{0}{2}".format(letter, "2:", "66").options(numbers=str).value)
        valueList[j].extend(val)
```

This is still not perfect though and there are probably other ways you could speed up your loops. You need to think about minimising what is done in your loop.